# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar un datagrid de devexpress?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, devexpress

Tengo el siguiente grid de DevExpress al cual le paso un modelo desde mi código en C#.

```
@{
    var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "GridCSA";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridCSA_Partial" };

        settings.CommandColumn.Visible = false;
        settings.SettingsPager.Visible = false;
        settings.Settings.ShowGroupPanel = true;
        settings.Settings.ShowFilterRow = false;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = false;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptivityMode = GridViewAdaptivityMode.Off;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveColumnPosition = GridViewAdaptiveColumnPosition.Right;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AdaptiveDetailColumnCount = 1;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.AllowOnlyOneAdaptiveDetailExpanded = false;
        settings.SettingsAdaptivity.HideDataCellsAtWindowInnerWidth = 0;
        settings.Settings.VerticalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Visible;
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Fecha_Apli";
            column.Caption = "Fecha de Aplicación";
            column.ReadOnly = true;
            column.Width = 130;
        });
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Num_Doc";
            column.Caption = "Número de documento";
            column.ReadOnly = true;
            column.Width = 150;
        });
        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Importe";
            column.Caption = "Importe";
            column.ReadOnly = true;
            column.Width = 100;
        });
    });
    if (ViewData["EditError"] != null)
    {
        grid.SetEditErrorText((string)ViewData["EditError"]);
    }
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

El problema que tengo es que desde una función de JS lo mando a llenar con un botón, el modelo se llena bien y hace la siguiente función:

```
public ActionResult ModeloGrid()
    {
        List<CUEN_DET01> Model = new List<CUEN_DET01>();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cadenaConexion"]);
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmnDet = new SqlCommand("select * from CUEN_DET01;", cn);
        SqlDataReader readDet = cmnDet.ExecuteReader();
        if (readDet.Read())
        {
            CUEN_DET01 datos;
            foreach (var det in readDet)
            {
                datos = new CUEN_DET01()
                {
                    Fecha_Apli = DateTime.Parse(readDet["FECHA_APLI"].ToString()),
                    Num_Doc = readDet["DOCTO"].ToString(),
                    Importe = Decimal.Parse(readDet["IMPORTE"].ToString()),
                    Refer = readDet["REFER"].ToString()
                };
                Model.Add(datos);
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
        Session["gridCSA"] = Model;
        GridCSA_Partial();
        return Json("success");
    }
```

Como pueden ver invoca el método donde le mando el modelo a la vista, que es este:

```
public ActionResult GridCSA_Partial()
    {
        List<CUEN_DET01> model = Session["gridCSA"] as List<CUEN_DET01>;
        return PartialView("~/Views/Home/_GridCSA_Partial.cshtml", model);
    }
```

Pero al terminar la función, por alguna razón no se refresca la data del grid y tengo que aplicarle un orden o una agrupación al grid desde la vista para que la información se actualice, mi pregunta es. ¿Cómo puedo actualizar el grid una ves termine mi función?

Les dejo el function de  JS que ocupo para aplicar todo lo anterior:

```
function GenerarGrid() {
    document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/ModeloGrid',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "success") {
                document.getElementById("load").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1) Èsto GridCSA_Partial(); return Json("success"); lo cambias por return GridCSA_Partial(); 2) todo ese $.ajax(.... lo cambias por $("#algun_ID_DE_UN_DIV").load('/Home/GridCSA_Partial')

Comment: Voy a probar, me queda duda sólo en quitar el ajax puesto que con esa función lleno el grid de datos entonces ahí no sé si sería quitarlo o modificarlo para que siga llamando al action "ModeloGrid()"

Comment: Listo, me funcionó perfecto. Lo modifiqué sin quitar el ajax pero agregando la línea que me pusiste, al igual cambié lo de "return GridCSA_Partial();" Muchas gracias!

Comment: la función load de jquery es un ajax encubierto